# password protection on root to view subdirectories

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, server

i do understand that we can password protect root/sub-directories using htacess.

what i want to achieve is create a user login system on root. and give different users access to different sub-directories and show list of sub-directories he have access to, when he logs in?

pls guide me in right direction (tutorial/script/hint).

thank you

i know some php but have mostly worked with cms (wordpress/joomla). i was thinking there should be some kind of login system to achieve what i want but my google skills failed me :(

Let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One database-based suggestion without .htaccess:

Part 1

Build a login system, there a lots of tutorials for that. The info if a user is logged in is stored in the $_SESSION, normally.

Part 2

Put your directory tree in a non-public folder. Then map your directory structure to a database table. Every table row represents a physical directory, and has the columns directory_id | parent_directory_id | directory_name | path_to_directory. Then, you need a table with only 2 columns user_id | directory_id where you store the relationship users <> allowed directories.

Part 3

Make use of the data in the tables to display or not display directories to your users. As the directories are in a non-public folder, you need php functions like scandir(), or, depending on your skill level, SPL classes like DirectoryIterator, to display the contents.